# modificar comportamiento del ultimo thread de un grupo

Tags: java, hilos

tengo el siguiente programa:

```
public class Corredor extends Thread {

    Testimoni comandament;
    static int canal;

    public Corredor(Testimoni c) {
        comandament = c;
        canal = 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        //Agafa el comandament
        comandament.agafa();

               System.out.println(getName() + " esta corren");

        //Mira la tele
        try {
            Thread.sleep((long) (Math.random() * 350) + 300);  //utilitzem el mètode sleep per suspendre l'execució del Thread un temps aleatori de ms
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            System.out.println("Error!!!");

        }
        System.out.println("Pasa el testimoni al seguent corredor:");
        //Deixa el comandament
        comandament.deixa();
    }
}


public class Relleus {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        Testimoni c = new Testimoni();
        int numMembres = 5; //la familia pot ser més gran o més petita

        //Es creen el membres de la família, se'ls dona un nom i es posen a mirar la tele
        Corredor[] membre = new Corredor[numMembres];
        for(int i=1; i<numMembres; i++) {
            membre[i] = new Corredor(c);
            membre[i].setName("CORREDOR : "+i);
            membre[i].start();
        }
        //Esperem que tots acabin de mirar la tele
        for(int i=1; i<numMembres; i++) {
            membre[i].join();
        }

        System.out.println("Carrera acabada!!");

    }
}


public class Testimoni  {
   /*
    * Modifiqueu i afegiu el codi necessari per implementar la classe 
    * Comandament.
    */
    boolean avalible = true;


    synchronized void agafa() {

        while (avalible == false) {
            try {
                wait();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {}
        }

        avalible = false;
        notify();
    }

    synchronized void deixa() {
        avalible = true;
        notify();
    }
}
```

Necesito hacer un if.

Que si el corredor 4 esta corriendo no pase el testimoni. Ahora esta hecho de tal forma que el testimonio 1 se lo pasa al 2, el 2 al 3 y el 3 al 4.. pero necesito que el 4 no lo haga.

En la clase RELLEUS es donde creo los corredores. Como puedo hacer para dentro de la clase CORREDOR pueda usar por ejemplo el membre[5] para poder hacerle un if dentro del método RUN()???
algo parecido a :
if corredor == membre[1], membre[2], membre[3]
pasa el testimonio.
else 
no pasa el testimonio.

El problema lo tengo que no se como puedo coger esos datos ni extrar esa información...

Gracias :(

Comment: no le puedes asignar un número a Corredor y así controlar cuál es? Sólo tendrías que hacer que si es el número 4 no pase el testimonio

Comment: @Pablo el orden de ejecucion no es determinado

Comment: Entonces pon ese parámetro en Testimoni y controla las veces que se ha pasado de un hilo a otro hasta que sean 4

Comment: vale y como lo hago? xD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tu no controlas quien le pasa el recurso concurrente a quien, todos los *threads* compiten por ese recurso y eventualmente todos terminaran ocupandolo en secuencia. Pero esta secuencia es indeterminada.

Por tanto, no puedes arbitrariamente decirle a un *thread* que no "pase" el testimoni a otro.

Una manera de solucionar el problema seria llevar un contador en la clase Testimoni de cuantas veces han liberado el recurso y podemos aprovechar el metodo `agafa()` para retornar esta cantidad a quien sea que tome el recurso:

```
public class Testimoni  {
   /*
    * Modifiqueu i afegiu el codi necessari per implementar la classe 
    * Comandament.
    */
    boolean avalible = true;
    int vecesLiberado = 0;

    synchronized int agafa() {
        while (avalible == false) {
            try {
                wait();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {}
        }

        avalible = false;
        notify();
        return vecesLiberado;
    }

    synchronized void deixa() {
        avalible = true;
        ++vecesLiberado;
        notify();
    }
}
```

Luego cada corredor al invocar a:

```
int veces = comandament.agafa();
```

Podra determinar si se ha cumplido o no la cantidad de veces para pasar el `Testimoni` a otro corredor.

Comment: gracias!! conseguido! :)